# How can I change location of default database for the warehouse?(spark)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive

```
    ...
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
        <value>hdfs://spark-master-01:9000/skybluelee/skybluelee_warehouse_mysql_5.7</value>
        <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
    </property>
    ...
```

the code is a part of /user/spark3/conf/hive-site.xml

At first the value was

```
hdfs://spark-master-01:9000/kikang/skybluelee_warehouse_mysql_5.7
```

And I changed the value

```
hdfs://spark-master-01:9000/skybluelee/skybluelee_warehouse_mysql_5.7
```

Below there is a code and result

```
println(spark.conf.get("spark.sql.warehouse.dir"))  //--Default : spark-warehouse

spark
    .sql("""
        SELECT 
            website, 
            avg(age) avg_age, 
            max(id) max_id
        FROM 
            people a 
            JOIN 
            projects b 
            ON a.name = b.manager 
        WHERE 
            a.age > 11 
        GROUP BY 
            b.website
        """)
    .write
    .mode("overwrite")  //--Overwrite mode....
    .saveAsTable("JoinedPeople")  //--saveAsTable(<warehouse_table_name>)....
    
sql("SELECT * FROM JoinedPeople").show(1000)

hdfs://spark-master-01:9000/skybluelee/skybluelee_warehouse_mysql_5.7
+--------------------+-------+------+
|             website|avg_age|max_id|
+--------------------+-------+------+
|http://hive.apach...|   30.0|     2|
|http://kafka.apac...|   19.0|     3|
|http://storm.apac...|   30.0|     9|
+--------------------+-------+------+
```

value 'spark.sql.warehouse.dir' was changed kikang into skybluelee as I want.

but the location of table "JoinedPeople" doesn't change. The location is 'hdfs://spark-master-01:9000/kikang/skybluelee_warehouse_mysql_5.7' - the first value in hive-site.xml

I want to change the location of default database.

How can I change the default location?

I changed 'spark-defaults.conf' and of courese turn off & on the ubuntu. But not effective

Answer (score 1):

I found what I missed!

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://spark-worker-01:3306/metastore_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
  <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
</property>
```

this is a part of warehouse in mysql_5.7
when I tried first in metastore_db was created, so even I changed the location,  that doesn't make change in metastore

Answer (score 0):

May you check what your Spark version is in this scenario?
According to [Hive Tables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html) in the official Spark documentation:

> Note that the hive.metastore.warehouse.dir property in hive-site.xml is deprecated since Spark 2.0.0. Instead, use spark.sql.warehouse.dir to specify the default location of database in warehouse. You may need to grant write privilege to the user who starts the Spark application.

1. Does changing the property in `hive-site.xml` work for you (assuming the Spark version is above 2.0.0)?

   ```xml
    ...
    <property>
        <name>spark.sql.warehouse.dir</name>
        <value>hdfs://spark-master-01:9000/skybluelee/skybluelee_warehouse_mysql_5.7</value>
        <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
    </property>
    ...
   ```
2. Does setting the property before the initialization of a Spark session work for you?

   ```scala
   import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

   val warehouseLocation = "hdfs://spark-master-01:9000/skybluelee/skybluelee_warehouse_mysql_5.7"

   // Create a SparkSession with the desired warehouse location
   val spark = SparkSession
     .builder()
     .appName("Spark Hive Example")
     .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
     .enableHiveSupport()
     .getOrCreate()

   // Import the necessary Spark functions and implicit
   import spark.implicits._
   import spark.sql
   sql("""
    SELECT 
        website, 
        avg(age) avg_age, 
        max(id) max_id
    FROM 
        people a 
        JOIN 
        projects b 
        ON a.name = b.manager 
    WHERE 
        a.age > 11 
    GROUP BY 
        b.website
    """)
      .write
      .mode("overwrite")
      .saveAsTable("JoinedPeople")

   // Retrieve the location of the "JoinedPeople" table from the Hive metastore
   val tableLocation = spark.sql("DESCRIBE EXTENDED JoinedPeople").filter($"col_name" === "Location").select("data_type").collect()(0)(0)
   println(s"Table location: $tableLocation")
   ```

Comment: First my spark version is above 3.2.1, Second I did your code, but it doesn't work. But I really thanks for your answer. Changing default location isn't necessary, and if I take a lecture about hive, maybe I can make it with your code. Thanks

Comment: I found the answer! If I post all hive-site.xml, then you maybe notice what I did wrong. Anyway I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: @skybluelee It is great to hear that you have resolved the issue! Have a good journey on exploring Spark :D